# Result callback in loop (Download multiple images from google drive.)

Tags: java, android, callback, google-drive-android-api

I am working on Google Drive Api. I want to download images from Google drive.
Below is the code which is working but the  files.open() is called when the loop finishes. Suppose the count is 3, the loop will complete looping first and after that files.open() will be called 3 times. Because of this I am not able to set the data in my model class. It takes only last value. (Edited)

```
    if (getGoogleApiClient() != null && getGoogleApiClient().isConnected()) {
        try {
            final DriveFolder pFldr = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient());
            pFldr.listChildren(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {
                    int count = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer().getCount();
                    Log.e("COUNT---", count + "");
                    MetadataBuffer buffer = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();
                    if (count > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            if (buffer.get(i).getMimeType().equals("image/jpeg")) {
                                Log.e("Images avaialbe - ", "" + buffer.get(i).getTitle());
                                DriveId id = buffer.get(i).getDriveId();
                                DriveFile files = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), id);
                                driveModel.setTitle(buffer.get(i).getTitle());

                                files.open(getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).setResultCallback(saveImageCallback);
                            }
                            if (buffer.get(i).getMimeType().equals("application/x-sqlite3")) {
                                DriveId id = buffer.get(i).getDriveId();
                                DriveFile files = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), id);
                                files.open(getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).setResultCallback(saveDataBaseCallback);
                            }
                        }

                        buffer.release();
                        showMessage("Success");
                    } else {
                        showMessage("No Back Up available.");
                    }
                }
            });

        } finally {

    }

}

        ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> saveImageCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult) {

                DriveContents cont = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
                InputStream inputStream = cont.getInputStream();
                try {

                    saveFiles(inputStream, driveModel.getTitle(), false);
                    cont.discard(getGoogleApiClient());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the catch for first `try-catch` ?

Comment: @GürtuğGüngör, it’s a try-finally, There is no catch.

Comment: @OleV.V., Sorry i was erased it mistakenly while editing then when i look my edited version i didn't see it and wrote the question.

Comment: It seems there never was a `catch`, but the OP edited in the `finally`. So I assume the code in the question is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
1.) Change to `ArrayList<DriveModel> driveFileList;`
2.)

```
 pFldr.listChildren
               (getGoogleApiClient())
               .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {
                 int count = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer().getCount();
                 Log.e("COUNT---", count + "");
                 Log.e("CHECk" , "Calling callback read from googledrive");
                 MetadataBuffer buffer = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();
                 if (count > 0) {
                     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                     final int finalI = i;

                     Log.e("CHECk" , "reading file " + buffer.get(i).getTitle());
                     Log.e("Files avaialbe - ", "" + buffer.get(i).getTitle());
                     driveModel=new DriveModel();
                     DriveId id = buffer.get(i).getDriveId();
                     DriveFile files = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), id);

                     if (buffer.get(i).getMimeType().equals("image/jpeg") ||
                           buffer.get(i).getMimeType().equals("image/png")) {

                          driveModel.setTitle(buffer.get(i).getTitle());
                          Log.e("Images avaialbe - ", "" + buffer.get(i).getTitle());
                          // driveModel.setTitle(buffer.get(i).getTitle());


                    files.open(getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                      .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                              @Override
                               public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult) {
                                               saveData(driveContentsResult, finalI);
                                    }
                                });
                                      driveFileList.add(driveModel);

                                      }

                    if (buffer.get(i).getMimeType().equals("application/x-sqlite3")) {

                           files.open(getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                                  .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult) {
                                      saveData(driveContentsResult, finalI);
                                 }
                             });

                          }

                      }

                              buffer.release();
                              showMessage("Success");
                     } else {
                               showMessage("No Back Up available.");
                            }

                           }
                 }

            );
```

3.) create the method :

```
 private void saveData(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult, int i) {
            Log.e("CHECk" , "Calling callback " + driveContentsResult.getDriveContents().getDriveId().encodeToString() );
            DriveContents cont = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();

            Log.e("File name :" ,  "File : " + driveFileList.get(i).getTitle());

//Put your code here
            InputStream inputStream = cont.getInputStream();
            try {

                saveFiles(inputStream, true);
                cont.discard(getGoogleApiClient());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException on driveFileList.get(i).getTitle();

Comment: you would be missing  driveFileList.add(driveModel); in your if conditions.. I didn't try for application/x-sqlite3 statement.

Comment: put some validations if you don't want to add File name for "application/x-sqlite3"